# Quick way/shortcut to navigate from the sheet to the formula bar

Tags: excel, shortcut

Is there a keyboard shortcut to move cursor from a cell in my sheet (i.e. cell) to the formula bar?

I have searched SO but cannot find answer.

(currently I leave the cursor hovering over the formula bar and left click mouse)

Comment: You can press `F2` to edit the content of the cell.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, you can mark it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for *programming questions*. This question has been already asked and [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/205733/how-can-i-change-the-focus-in-excel-to-the-formula-bar-via-the-keyboard) on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the shortcut for editing a cell is <kbd>F2</kbd> and if you're using Mac then it's <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

With Excel's default settings, this will edit directly in the cell, the same as double-clicking the cell will.

If you want to always edit cells in the formula bar, even when you use a keyboard shortcut, you'll need to disable "*Allow editing directly in cells*" in the settings.

The actual settings may look different than this image for the version you are using.

[image: Allow editing directly in cells]